# Hardware Reserved Memory - Windows 7 32-bit (Bootcamp)

Tags: memory, windows-7, hardware, bootcamp

I been looking into this problem for about a week now and officially can't find a solution. I have Windows 7 installed on my MacBook Pro Early 2011 13-inch through bootcamp and there is 1880 MB of my RAM under Hardware Reserve. Under the system information it says 4.00GB ram available (2.16GB usable). I was wondering if there is anyway I can release or free up some of this memory?

I have already read so many recommendations of going into msconfig and making sure that the max memory is unticked and it is already unticked. In addition, some people mentioned upgrading to the 64-bit version of Windows 7, but I see that some other people tried this and had no success.

Let me know if you would like any additional info, like from CPU-Z. Thanks.

Comment: I'm have the same problem with my MacBook Air 13" (mid 2011 i think) with 4gb ram installed; exact same 1880 MB 'Hardware Reserved'. MSCONFIG doesn't work for me either. Help please!

Answer (score -1):

A couple of possibilities I've found:

-Personal Experience: Try 64 bit. While it may not work, it's definitely worth a shot. 32 bit Windows limits the amount of usable RAM. While this doesn't fully explain your issue, I'd be interested to hear the results (also suggested [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1230627) and [here](http://www.qa.downappz.com/questions/mac-install-win7-via-boot-camp-only-2-of-4gb-ram-is-usable.html) and [here](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/page-265106_30_50.html)).

-[Incorrect Memory Configuration](https://superuser.com/questions/56157/why-is-all-my-extra-ram-marked-as-hardware-reserved-in-windows-7)

-Although you said it didn't work, it still appeared to be a valid fix for some people's issue ([source](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1316116)):

`Start>msconfig in the search box>Go to the Boot tab>Untick 'maximum memory' box`

Do any of these suggestions solve your issue?